# How to lock a file for multiple computers in windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, file-io

(In c++)I want to make a process that will run on multiple computers that share the same file (on the same hard disk). And from each process I want to write to the end of a file, but only when no other process is using that file.

How can I lock that file when writing to it, or at least check if another process is using it?

Comment: Can you elaborate? what is "multiply computer windows"?

Comment: i fixed the spelling mistake, I have a few computers that all share the same hard disk.

Comment: How do they share it? SMB, NFS, shared SCSI bus, FC?

Comment: Can that even work, conceptually? I can imagine SMB or NFS, but several machines sending SCSI commands via fiber concurrently... how could possibly filesystem metadata be maintained or such things as journalling be done?

Comment: In my understanding, you generally have no atomicity guarantees between writes on a physical disk without locking, but a _single_ write call is guaranteed to be atomic. Since SMB calls write in the end, this should not be any different over SMB either, as long as you send everything in a single block write request (unless the SMB server is broken and deliberately splits up blocks for no reason). It is something I would at least try, because if it works, you can do without any locking at all, merely by making sure to put everything that belongs together into one block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you will try to open the file, it will fail if it is already being used. 
To see if opening has failed, you can either :

- Check [`ios::fail()`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/fail/)
- Call [`ios::exceptions()`](http://cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ios/exceptions/) before opening the file,